# Problem in updating profile

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I am trying to change my name of my profile but getting **Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:unusual error updating your profile -- please try again!**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried on the other sites? If so, flag this post to be migrated to Meta.SO, as it is network wide...

Comment: No I haven't tried on any other sites. Today, I tried and it works. Yesterday, I was getting this error.

Comment: The developers probably issued a hot fix and this isn't relevant anymore. I would suggest you delete the post.

Comment: There was issue yesterday so I posted, if you think that this isn't relevant questions anymore then flag it for deletion.

Comment: Okay. I will. Just as a note, I did the same thing, and a fix was issued, and I deleted the post. Just so you know I'd do the same thing to my post.

Comment: This is not a topic of debate. I think it should be there for community awareness as it is bug as you can see in screen shot. I didn't get any indication that issue has been fix or not.

Comment: Nor did I when I posted my question...

Comment: @daviesgeek We don't delete issues, even transient ones. You know this.

Comment: @JasonSalaz Actually, I disagree. bmike I believe will agree with me. He asked me to delete one of my questions, as it wasn't relevant anymore.

Comment: [tag:status-nonrepro]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed. Today, I tried and got success in changing name.

It was there yesterday it might be a *bug* but now it has been solved.